# TextProperty in TextBox not being updated after input text;

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have this textbox in Input.xaml:

```
 <TextBox Name="input"
     IsEnabled = "{Binding ElementName = control, Path = InputEnabled}"
     Text = "{Binding Input, ElementName = control, UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged}"
     />
```

in Input.xaml.cs :

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty InputProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Input",
    typeof(string),
    typeof(InputPanel),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("")
    );

public static readonly DependencyProperty InputEnabledProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "InputEnabled",
    typeof(bool),
    typeof(InputPanel),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(true)
    );

public string Input
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(InputProperty); }
    set { SetValue(InputProperty, value); }
}

public bool InputEnabled
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(InputEnabledProperty); }
    set { SetValue(InputEnabledProperty, value); }
}
//...
```

I update the property Input from the Windows.xaml as follows:

```
   <local:Input Input = "{Binding Path = Selected.ETA, Mode = OneWay}"/>
```

That works perfectly, but when I change the Text Property form the GUI, the binding won't work anymore. There is a way to still work with the binding after a Text enter from the GUI.

Comment: What do you mean by _change the Text Property form the GUI_?

Comment: change the `mode = OneWay` to `mode = TwoWay`

Comment: I mean when you insert a text from the visual in the textbox, not by the data binding.

Comment: you have `ElementName = control` but where is the element named control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your `binding` mode as follows:

```
  <local:Input Input = "{Binding Path = Selected.ETA, Mode = TwoWay}"/>
```

That way you will be allowed to update underlying properties from UI and update UI from underlying property. Remember you also have to implement `INotifyPropertyChange` interface. More information about `INotifyPropertyChange` could be found [here](http://www.wpftutorial.net/INotifyPropertyChanged.html).